# my apk stopped when starting to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-button

Im new to android development. Im trying to open second activity by clicking button, but when I try my apk stopped. can someone help me figure out my error. Below are my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pradeep.findme">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainPlayActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.pradeep.findme.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/uibg"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"        >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/pbutton"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:textColor="#0760db"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibutton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/inst"
        android:textColor="#0760db"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pbutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/sbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/story"
        android:textColor="#0760db"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ibutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ebutton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/exit"
        android:textColor="#0760db"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sbutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button Quit,Play,Story,Ins;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Quit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ebutton);
    Play= (Button)findViewById(R.id.pbutton);
    Story= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sbutton);
    Ins= (Button)findViewById(R.id.ibutton);

    Quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPlayActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

activity_main_play.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.pradeep.findme.MainPlayActivity"
android:background="@drawable/room2"
android:id="@+id/playscreen"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainPlayActivity.java

```
public class MainPlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_play);
}
}
```

Comment: post error log here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to apply theme.
Put `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in your manifest file like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Thanks its works, but second activity not started with full screen with have titlebar, but i mentioned to use the theme without titlebar and full screen

Comment: @Pradeep you've not applied "Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE" in the second activity. Apply the same in second activity also and then check.

Comment: still its not working i added  "Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE" like in mainactivity

Comment: @Pradeep Try "getSupportActionBar().hide();" once.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use `R.layout.activity_main_play`
What is `R.layout.activity_main_play`?

Possible solution:
Rename `SecondActivity.xml` to `activity_main_play.xml`

But first of all you should take a look on the error log.

Comment: i'm using activity_main_play.xml, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Pradeep so, could you give us the error log anyway?

Comment: com.example.pradeep.findme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.pradeep.findme, PID: 2390 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pradeep.findme/com.example.pradeep.findme.MainPlayActi‌​vity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.